# Is there an agreed standard to associate a time stamp with a Shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, xml

There are many reasons one might like to store temporal information in association with a shapefile. In my case I want a manually accessible timestamp so I can request temporally relative updates to a dataset.

Is there a proper way to do this in the shapefile standard? (or perhaps another QGIS accessible file standard)

I've had a look and the most appropriate place I could find seemed to me to be the geospatial metadata file (suffix .shp.xml) but I can't see how or if one can actually read or write a time stamp to that file.

The next thing I thought was to store a time stamp directly into the file name but that seems a little hacky for such an important factor.

To be clear I don't want to store a time stamp attribute for *features* in my shapefile as in [GIS file format for space and time data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55098) That would be straight forward but not appropriate. I want to store a timestamp for THE shapefile.

Using a timestamp assigned to the files by the OS (e.g.: file creation date or file access date) is also possible but that doesn't give me enough control and may be changed inappropriately by the OS later.

I use QGIS, but if there's no option available to QGIS, then writing my own XML (or similar) reader in Python is a viable solution too.

Comment: You can conceptually put anything into the `.shp.xml` sidecar, but I'd be interesting in knowing if there is any existing implementation of this particular aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native way would be to use the "Date of last update" data field of the dbf file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf. However, it is formatted as YYMMDD and can not hold time. If that is accurate enough you can control the value of the field with GDAL through the shapefile driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html with the layer creation option (-lco) DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE.

> DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=YYYY-MM-DD: (OGR >= 2.0) Modification date to
>   write in DBF header with year-month-day format. If not specified,
>   current date is used. Note: behaviour of past GDAL releases was to
>   write 1995-07-26

GDAL can naturally also read the value of DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE and for example ogrinfo shows it.

Comment: It's a shame that the current QGIS (2.16) is GDAL/OGR<2.0 because I can imagine a pyQGIS implementation from here using GDAL and it's python bindings. While running more than one version of GDAL in a single system might be possible it's problematic. Perhaps hacking a workaround until the hard working people who support QGIS catches it up would be best. It's certainly worked before!

Comment: QGIS 2.18 is compiled and running against gdal 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

In the US for shapefile data the standard has been to put this  information in the shp.xml file.  The [Federal Geographic Data Committee (FGDC)](https://www.fgdc.gov/metadata) has been the lead in setting these standards.  The data time stamp info could be stored in either the Identification Information or Maintenance Information section (see [Geospatial Metadata Fact Sheet pdf](https://www.fgdc.gov/resources/factsheets/documents/GeospatialMetadata-July2011.pdf)).  As far as metadata editors in QGIS you may a quick search turns up [Metatools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/metatools/).  FDGC also has a page on available metadata editing tools.

[Geospatial Metadata Tools](https://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/geospatial-metadata-tools#availabletools)